# Why does Range work, but not Cells?

Tags: vba, range, cells

I'm trying to move some data from one workbook into another by assigning the values from one range to another. When I use the normal Range syntax to specify the destination range (Range("A1:B2")) my code works, but if I try to use the Range, Cells syntax (Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))) my code doesn't work.

I activate the destination workbook (ActiveWorkbook) and have the code running in the source workbook (ThisWorkbook).

This code works:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B2").Value _
= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value
```

But This code does not:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value _
= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Value
```

The error I get is Run-time error '1004': Applicaton-defined or object-defined error.

Does anyone know why using the cells object is causing me problems, or if there is some other problem I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 49):

The problem is that `Cells` is unqualified, which means that the sheet to which those cells refer is different depending on where your code is. Any time you call `Range` or `Cells` or `Rows` or `UsedRange` or anything that returns a Range object, and you don't specify which sheet it's on, the sheet gets assigned according to:

- In a sheet's class module: that sheet regardless of what's active
- In any other module: the ActiveSheet

You qualify the `Range` reference, but the `Cells` reference is unqualified and is likely pointing to the Activesheet.  It's like writing

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheetCells(2, 2)).Value
```

which of course doesn't make any sense unless ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) happens to be active. I often like to use a With block so that I make sure everything is fully qualified.

```
With Sheets(1)
    .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(2,2)).Value = "something"
End With
```

But you refer to two different sheets, so you'll be better off using short sheet variables like:

```
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim shDest As Worksheet

Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set shDest = Workbooks("myBook").Worksheets(1)

shDest.Range(shDest.Cells(1, 1), shDest.Cells(2, 2)).Value = _
    shSource.Range(shSource.Cells(1, 1), shSource.Cells(2, 2)).Value
```

But really, if you're going to hardcode the `Cells` arguments, you could clean that up like

```
shDest.Cells(1, 1).Resize(2, 2).Value = shSource.Cells(1, 1).Resize(2, 2).Value
```

Comment: no need to qualify the range in the instruction `shDest.Range(shDest.Cells(1, 1), shDest.Cells(2, 2)).Value = _
    shSource.Range(shSource.Cells(1, 1), shSource.Cells(2, 2)).Value ` this is also correct `Range(shDest.Cells(1, 1), shDest.Cells(2, 2)).Value= _
   Range(shSource.Cells(1, 1), shSource.Cells(2, 2)).Value`

Comment: @h2so4 - Wait - so does that mean you don't have to qualify the `Range()` if you do the `Cells()` inside? Is that explicitly correct, or does it "just work"...I've always qualified all parts of a `Range(cells(),Cells())` and it'd be neat if I can skip the `Range()` qualifier ...

Comment: @BruceWayne, Excel documentation that I have found so far is not clear about this. (I have found that prefixing the range is a must in a sheet module, but not needed in any other type of modules. Is this explicitly correct or does it just work by chance, I don't know ...

Comment: My guess (and it's only a guess) is that it's explicitly correct. Since Range can take a variery of parameter types - a string that evaluates to a range, a single cell object, two cell objects - that there is stuff going on behind the scenes to evaluate what kind of parameter you're sending. If you send a fully qualified cell object, I'll bet that it skips most of the evaluating/converting code and it's the straightest path through the code. Like it doesn't convert it to a string and then back to a cell. So for my money, you can omit the reference from Range if Cells are qualified.

Comment: And I will still probably type it because I'm a creature of habit.

Comment: While leaving Range unqualified does work, qualifying it too it slightly faster.

Comment: A thought on error proofing:  if one habitually uses the @Dick Kusleika 's sytnax of a "with" block and dot-qualified .range and .cell ,  does it not force the programmer away from mis-directed references, and force the later reader/debugger to understand the intent (even if it's all the original programmer...... ! )