# I am getting Runtime error 1004 when using Range class for creating a macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am trying to automate one report in Excel. I started with creating macro. At one point in macro I am copying one row from AZ2 to CJ2  using variables, each cell has formulas and I want to paste the same formulas from AZ3 to AZ248000.  I am getting error for this code Wb1.Sheets("Gains Data").Range(Cells(row3, Col1), Cells(Row2, Col1)).Select

I already tried number of examples and solutions provided online, I started with autofill, also tried to just pasting formula. I tried to activate file, sheet, worksheet as suggested for the similar problems online.  Nothing worked.  Please check my code and advise the solution.
PS - before this code there is bunch of code where I am copying data from different workbook Wb2 onto the main one Wb1.

```
   Dim Row1 As Long
   Dim Row2 As Long
   Dim row3 As Long
   Dim Col1 As String
   Dim Col2 As String

   Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range("AY2").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   Row2 = ActiveCell.Row

 ' Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range("AZ2").Select
       ' Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ' Col2 = ActiveCell.Column


Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range("AZ2").Select
Row1 = ActiveCell.Row
row3 = Row1 + 1
Col1 = ActiveCell.Column
Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range(Selection, 
Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'Col2 = ActiveCell.Column
Selection.Copy
'Windows("Gains SOP Forecast Comparison 2019 07.xlsb").Activate
 Wb1.Sheets("Gains Data").Activate

'Range("O1:X1").Select

'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Col1 & Row1 & ":" & Col2 & Row2), 
  Type:=xlFillDefault

'Range("BA3:B" & LastRow1 & ":" & "CJ3:CJ" & LastRow1).Formula=

 'Cells(Col1 & Row1 & ":" & Col2 & Row2).Paste
 'Sheets("Gains Data").Range(Col1 & row3 & ":" & Col1 & Row2).Select
 Wb1.Sheets("Gains Data").Range(Cells(row3, Col1), Cells(Row2, 
 Col1)).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste  ' Copies the formulas from BA to CJ for all rows
```

The formulas should be copied down to all the rows depending on number of rows Wb2 has which I am storing in the row2 variable.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/62576) will help you solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: You need to qualify the `Worksheet` the `Cells` are on. Otherwise `ActiveSheet` is implied, which may not be `Wb1.Sheets("Gains Data")`. Using a `With...End With` block will make this easier.

Comment: Thanks I am trying  This Wb1.Sheets("Gains Data").Activate
    With Ws1
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range(Col1 & Row1 & ":" & Col2 & Row1)
    Set rng2 = Wb1.Worksheets("Gains Data").Range(Col1 & Row3 & ":" & Col1 & Row2)
    rng1.Copy rng2
    End With   -----------------Now Row2 has got value of 248500 I am still getting error 1004 for rng2 is it because of Row2 number is so high?

Comment: `Dim Col1 as Long`, not `As String`. Same for `Col2`. Then use `Cells` instead of `Range`.

Comment: See the answer I linked to in the comment above for how to use `With...End With`.

Comment: This worked, hurray thanks :-) >>>>>Dim Col1 as Long, not As String. Same for Col2. Then use Cells instead of Range

Answer (score 0):

If you need copy the data from one workbook to another, please try below code:

```
Sub Copy_Between_Workbook()
Dim wb_path$
Dim wb1, wb2
Dim i, j

wb_path = ThisWorkbook.Path    'Path of workbook
myfile1 = "workbook1.xlsx"
myfile2 = "workbook2.xlsx"
mysheet = "Sheet1"
'Original workbook
Set wb1 = CreateObject(wb_path & "\" & myfile1)
'Target workbook
Set wb2 = CreateObject(wb_path & "\" & myfile2)
'attend: wb1.sheet1 is not work, must be wb1.sheets("xxx")
wb1.Sheets(mysheet).UsedRange.Copy wb2.Sheets(mysheet).Range("A1")

wb1.Close False
wb2.Close True

'Out cut mode
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting error when I am copying formulas from range (AZ2, CJ2) and pasting from (AZ3,AZ248000)