# VBA error when copying and pasting between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate copying data from `Workbook x Sheet 1` into `Workbook 2 Sheet 2` below the last row with values

To copy selection:

```
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("A9"), Range("A9").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
```

To paste selection:

```
y.Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A923").PasteSpecial
```

I get an Application.defined or Object.defined error whenever I run it.

I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `x` and what is `y` in your VBA code?

Comment: @Xukrao x is workbook 1 and y is workbook 2

Comment: The two instances of `Range("A9")` are unqualified - you need to specify the workbook and worksheet they are in/on. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) is similar even though it uses `Cells` instead of `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen I want to copy all rows and columns with data starting from cell A9, from workobook 1 (x) to workbook 2 (y).

Comment: I'm just trying to point out the cause of the error. I think the accepted answer to the question I linked to is a good explanation of why you get the error, as well as a possible solution.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for pointing that out, I missed the link. I'm not very familiar with vba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Range function expects a reference to the sheet. You specified the sheet in the first entry, but you should mention it in every Range method.

Please see code below:

```
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9"), x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
```

Doing this is not recommended as it gets tough to read the code, so you can save the sheet in a variable adn use the variable further like below:

```
Dim Main_Sheet as Worksheet

Set Main_Sheet = x.Sheets("Sheet1")

Main_Sheet.Range(Main_Sheet.Range("A9"), Main_Sheet.Range("A9").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
```