# Copy Data from Multiple Workbook to main file

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula and Im getting Error 1004, saying that file was possible removed or renamed or deleted, but in reality file is just there.

Im getting the error on this line : Workbooks.Open (MyFile)

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String 
Dim erow MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\congresojr.5\Desktop\Puller Sample\sample file\")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zzzPuller.xlsm" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open (MyFile) Range("B11:J31").Copy ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = RawPuller.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste
Destination:=Worksheets("RawPuller").Range(Cells(erow, 2),
Cells(erow, 10))

MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Worksheets("RawPuller").Range(Worksheets("RawPuller").Cells(erow, 2),
Worksheets("RawPuller").Cells(erow, 10))`?

Comment: Hi, im getting the error on this line : Workbooks.Open (MyFile)

Comment: Before `Workbooks.Open`, put `Debug.Print myFile`, what's the output?

Comment: You need the full path and the file name.

Comment: @BruceWayne i have the same error

Comment: @BigBen yes, full path is indicated. Yet im trying to understand how the filename works since im trying to get the data from all of the workbook in the folder

Comment: @nathanielCongreso - see my answer. You need the full path in the `Workbooks.Open` call.

Comment: You need to clarify if you are trying to open all the workbooks in the path or just one workbook "zzzPuller".

Comment: @GMalc what im trying to do is open the workbooks on a specific folder one by one, copy a range and paste it to zzzpuller

Comment: You will need to loop through the folder, open each file, and copy the range and paste to the destination worksheet. I have a question is `Worksheets("RawPuller")` `in Workbooks("zzzPuller.xlsm")`?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on how to accomplish this; either do a SO search or Google search for "excel vba open all files in folder and copy range", I got About 1,760,000 results in Google

Answer (score 0):

`Dir` only returns the file name. You need both the path and the filename in the `Workbooks.Open` call to avoid the error you're getting.

Additionally, avoid relying on an implicit or explicit `ActiveWorkbook`.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\congresojr.5\Desktop\Puller Sample\sample file\" & MyFile)
```

Now you can work with `wb`:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Range("B11:J31").Copy
...
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) for why

```
Worksheets("RawPuller").Range(Cells(erow, 2), Cells(erow, 10))
```

is problematic.

Comment: BigBen, as i thought, the OP wants to open the folder and loop through all(?) workbook files. He obviously doesn't understand how to loop through each file, open it, and copy the same range to `Worksheets("RawPuller")`