# Dynamic Autofill Destination

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help with this code:

```
Dim numRows As Long

numRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(numRows, 12)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The macro is supposed to fill column L with a formula. It works with files with multiple rows but ends with:

> Autofill method of Range class failed.

For files with only one row.

Comment: It will fail the autofill if there is nothing to autofill. This is expected behaviour, and this might be one of the few valid cases you could use `On Error Resume Next` to get around it. Alternatively, you could use an if statement to test if `numRows > 1`, and skip the autofill when true.

Comment: @Plutian Don't use `On Error Resume Next` this is a very bad practice! And it will soon or later result in other issues. Instead check for `If numRows > 1 Then  'do autofill`. You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: You can use `.Formula` to enter the values in the entire range in one go... `ws.Range("L1:L" & numRows).Formula = ws.Range("L1").Formula` Where `ws` is the respective sheet. BTW your cells are not fully qualified. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the share, definitely a good read. I realised my advise was bad as soon as I started typing up the answer, so I amended with the preferred method and a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

Tips:

1. Avoid the use of `Selection`. In your code, the selection may not be the "selection" you think it is ;) You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. Your objects are not fully qualified. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)
3. You can use `.Formula` to enter the values in the entire range in one go.

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change as applicable

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("L1:L" & lRow).Formula = .Range("L1").Formula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I expected when pasting the same formula to an entire range as in your answer, it would copy the same formula to all cells, instead of auto-incrementing. But after testing found it doesn't work like that. Interesting...

Answer (score 2):

Test if the row count is equal to or lower than zero with an if statement:

```
Dim numRows As Long

With Sheets("Yoursheetname")

    numRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Not numRows <= 1 Then .Cells(1, 12).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, 12), .Cells(numRows, 12)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End With
```

As per my comment, you could also use `On Error Resume Next`:

```
Dim numRows As Long

numRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next 'turn of error handling for the next statement

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(numRows, 12)), Type:=xlFillDefault

On Error GoTo 0 'turn error handling back on
```

Edit: as per @Peh's comment, the first one is preferred, as turning off error handling (even for one statement) might become problematic if you code has (or develops) any other issues.

Comment: Avoid the use of selection :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Edited without the use of selection, used explicit sheet references throughout the code as well. [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: ++ nice.. btw `If Not numRows <= 1` can be written as `If numRows > 1` :)

Comment: This is what overthinking looks like :P

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 1 Then .Range("L1:L" & lr).FillDown
End With

End Sub
```