# Mismatch type errors involving Columns("U2:U") and cells( , ).address

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a programme that finds the "Reliability Fail" header and checks whether the data below this header is >0. If is more than 0, it will offset(0,3) to the right and put the value that i have obtained using left function .As i am still not very familiar with VBA syntax, im facing the mismatch type error as shown below. Does anybody knows how to solve it?

```
 Dim arr As Variant
    With Application
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim z As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim result As Long
    lastrow2 = ws1.Columns("U2:U").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row '--->**mistmatch error here**
    arr = .Transpose(ws1.Range("T1:W1").Value)
    For p = 2 To lastrow2
    If .Count(.Match(Array("Reliability Fail"), arr, 0)) = 1 And ws1.Cells(p, "U") > 1 Then
    result = ws1.Cells(p, "U").Address(False, False) '---->**mismatch error here**
    ws1.Cells(Range("result").Row, Range("result").Column).Offset(0, 3) = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
    End If
    Next

End With
```

Updated changes:

```
Dim arr As Variant
With Application
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim z As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim resultRng As Range
Set resultRng = ws1.Cells(p, "U")
lastrow2 = ws1.Columns("U2:U & ws1.Rows.Count").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
arr = .Transpose(ws1.Range("T1:W1").Value)
For p = 2 To lastrow2
If ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail"And resultRng > 1 Then
ws1.Cells(p, "U").Offset(0,3).Value = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: `U2:U` is not a valid range reference.

Comment: @BigBen why is it so? My intention here is to select the entire column U starting from 2nd row...

Comment: Also `Range.Address` returns a `String`, not a `Long`.

Comment: `"U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count`. You need a row number.

Comment: @BigBen btw is my syntax for converting the cells.address into cells( , ) correct? Because i suppose offset can only be used in this way?

Comment: no quotes around `result`

Comment: Just use a `Range` object: `Dim resultRng as Range`, `Set resultRng = ws1.Cells(p, "U")`, `resultRng.Offset(0,3) = ...`. Don't work with addresses, that's overcomplicating things, and setting yourself up for possible [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells).

Comment: @BigBen i just make an updated changes, so is this ok?

Comment: Eh I would just use a `Range` object as I mentioned in my previous comment. Though I take back the point of errors - that would happen if you did `Range(Cells)` but that's not the case.

Comment: Change *everything* inside the `If...End If` to `ws1.Cells(p, "U").Offset(0,3).Value = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)`.

Comment: @BigBen U mean replacing ws1.Cells(p, "U") to resultRng? Yeah i did but right now im facing the application defined error at the line starting  from lastrow2...

Comment: you are also using `.Count(.Match(Array("Reliability Fail"), arr, 0)) = 1` to test whether the title is there but always refer to column U.  Why not just `ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `"U2:U"` is not a valid range (or column) reference.  You need a row number. And use `Range` instead of `Columns`: `ws1.Range("U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count)`. Though I really think you just need `ws1.Columns("U:U")` here.
2. `Range.Address` returns a `String`, e.g. `$A$1`, not a `Long`.
3. Simplifying, just change

   ```
   result = resultRng.Address(False, False)
   resultRng.Offset(0,3) = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
   ```

   to

   ```
   ws1.Cells(p, "U").Offset(0,3).Value = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
   ```

---

Thanks to @Scott Craner for incorporating these changes into the following revised code:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

If ws1.Range("U1") = "Reliability Fail" Then
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    lastrow2 = ws1.Range("U2:U" & ws1.Rows.Count).Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

    For p = 2 To lastrow2
        If ws1.Cells(p, "U").Value > 1 Then
            ws1.Cells(p, "U").Offset(0, 3).Value = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: @ScottCraner but i still got the application defined or object defined error at lastrow2 line tho..

Comment: @cena - change `Columns` to `Range`.

Comment: @cena did you try the updated code that BigBen has, they fixed my error.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry i missed out just now