# Excel does not update function automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet for calculating maximum drawdown, that is, what is the highest percentage of drop in relation to the top. In this case it is the highest possible negative percentage.
[image]

[image]

It can be seen that the biggest drop is between $ 90 and $ 40 from (13) to (14).
My VBA looked like this:

```
Public Function MDD(ByVal iRange As Variant, ByVal fRange As Variant) As Variant
    Dim primLinha As Integer
    Dim coluna As Integer
    Dim ultLinha As Integer
    Dim contador As Integer
    Dim MDDTemp As Variant
       
    primLinha = Mid(iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("R", iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) + 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("C", iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) - 2)
    coluna = Mid(iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("C", iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) + 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("C", iRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) + 1)
    ultLinha = Mid(fRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("R", fRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) + 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("C", fRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)) - 2)
    contador = primLinha
    MDD = 0
    
    While contador <= ultLinha
        MDDTemp = Cells(contador, coluna) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(primLinha, coluna), Cells(contador, coluna))) - 1
   
        If MDDTemp < MDD Then
           MDD = MDDTemp
        End If
      
        contador = contador + 1
    Wend
    
End Function
```

But I have a problem with the formula update! For example, if I have the formula = MDD (A2; A21) in cell D3 (the result is -55.6%), after that if I decide to update the data from $ 90 to $ 30, the formula in D3 continues to show -55, 6%, when it should show -62.5%, is only updated when I double click on D3 and then 'Enter'. I have already enabled the automatic update of Excel, but nothing. Is it a mistake in VBA?

My Test:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use `.Address` like you're using.

Comment: `Range(Cells(primLinha, coluna), Cells(contador, coluna))` is problematic too, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells).

Comment: are your calcs set to automatic or manual?

Comment: because I need to know the first and last line in numerical values

Comment: @Scott Craner Auto

Comment: If you're going to use your arguments as ranges, then make them `Range`s: `ByVal iRange As Range, ByVal fRange As Range`.

Comment: And a `Range` has a `Row` and `Column` property... not sure why you're doing all the `Mid` and `Address` parsing as mentioned previously.

Comment: You will need to make the function volatile as you are only providing two cells instead of the range.  Add `Application.Volitile` as the first  line in the function.

Comment: my biggest problem is when it comes to knowing which line starts and ends, because i have to test one by one in the 'while'

Comment: @BigBen 
I used the 'Address' function to change from A2 to R2C1 and then I used 'Mid' to remove R + C1 and I got the line = 2 and then I removed the R2C and I got the column = 1

Comment: Why though? That's super roundabout. `Range("A2").Column` returns `1`. `Range("A2").Row` returns `2`.

Comment: With office 365: `=MIN(A2:A25/(MAXIFS(OFFSET(A2,0,,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A25))),OFFSET(A2,0,,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A25))),"<>0"))-1)`

Comment: @BigBen first of all, did you understand how the maximum drawdown is calculated?

Comment: Yes... I'm trying to fix an issue with your code. Multiple issues actuallly.

Comment: So, the only way I found that the rows and the column were using 'Mid' and 'Address' to be used in the MDD calculation

Comment: And I'm telling you that your approach is super roundabout and not how it should be done.

Comment: `primLinha = iRange.Row` : `coluna = iRange.Column` ....

Comment: I am thinking of another logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variant array to speed things up and use the entire range in the criterion:

```
Function MDD(rng As Range) As Double
 
    If rng.Cells.Count < 2 Or rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rngArray As Variant
    rngArray = rng.Value
    
    Dim mx As Double
    mx = 0
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(rngArray, 1) To UBound(rngArray, 1)
    
        If mx < rngArray(i, 1) Then mx = rngArray(i, 1)
        
        Dim MDDTemp As Double
        MDDTemp = (rngArray(i, 1) / mx) - 1
        
        If MDDTemp < MDD Then MDD = MDDTemp
    Next i


End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should go back to posting answers instead of all the back-and-forth comments. Saves a headache, I feel. Thanks for posting (and yes, I refuse to use the new 'say thanks' button).