# copy multiple sheet if cell()>0

Tags: excel, vba

I need a little help. It is first time when I write here... usually you are my inspiration, but now i didn't find something to help me.

I have an Excel file with 36 sheets. I want to create a macro to copy each sheet and make it a distinct file. The condition is that the cell(X)value to be `>0`. I have a problem with `if then`... that is jumping from first sheet to final sheet... or only saves the first sheet and ignores the other. I put here the script for only two sheet..because is working only at the first. Thanks for help.

```vb
Sub Macro3()   
    Sheets("A").Select

    If Range("G4").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets("A").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$12:$L$22").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        Range("B15:B22").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Range("C15").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Range("B12").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        
        ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop\POSM"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Range("D4").Value), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close
    End If
    
    Sheets("B").Select
    
    If Range("G4").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets("B").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$12:$L$22").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        Range("B15:B22").Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Range("C15").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Range("B12").Select
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
      
        ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop\POSM"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Range("D4").Value), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close

        MsgBox ("Finish")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will probably figure why it happens if you visit https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733541/11683.

Answer (score 1):

You keep [selecting ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683) for no reason and relying on the [implicit active sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733541/11683) that may not necessarily be what you think it is after all those selects.

You don't need to do any of that:

```vb
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim w_copy As Worksheet

For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If w.Range("G4").Value > 0 Then
    
    w.Copy
    Set w_copy = ActiveSheet
    
    With w_copy
      .Range("B12:L22").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
      .Range(.Range("C15"), .Range("C15").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
      .ShowAllData
      
      .Parent.SaveAs "C:\Users\Desktop\POSM\" & .Range("D4").Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
      .Parent.Close False
    End With
    
  End If
Next
```