# How to reference UsedRange in non active sheet in MS EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, worksheet

The code works fine when the sheet with the data to be sorted is active (sheet2). But I actually have the macro button on a different sheet (sheet1). This is the code in the module:

```
    Sheet2.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range("O1"), Key2:=Range("L1"), Key3:=Range("I1"), Header:=xlYes, _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Order3:=xlDescending
```

When I run the macro from the button in sheet1 (ie sheet 1 is now the active sheet, but not with the data that needs sorting) I get Run-time error 1004, the sort reference is not valid. This is because there's no data on the now active sheet (sheet1).

How can I reference the usedrange in sheet 2 properly so it will sort the data despite the sheet being inactive?

Comment: [Interesting Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't `Sheet2.UsedRange`, but the unqualified `Range` calls for the key parameters, which means that implicitly these are `ActiveSheet.Range("O1")`, `ActiveSheet.Range("L1")` and so on.

Either add `Sheet2` before each `Range` call, or perhaps use a `With` block and make sure to add a period `.` before each `Range` call, as well as before `UsedRange`.

```vb
With Sheet2
    .UsedRange.Sort Key1:=.Range("O1"), Key2:=.Range("L1"), Key3:=.Range("I1"), Header:=xlYes, _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Order3:=xlDescending
End With
```