# VBA Double FOR loop with an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I need a VBA script that will perform a double FOR loop. The first FOR loop, is a loop that needs to perform a few commands over multiple sheets (The first sheet is the main sheet and needs to be skipped!!)

The second for loop needs to compare values on multiple rows. I have pasted my code so far...

```
Public Sub LoopOverSheets()
device = Cells(6, 1) 'This value is whatever the user chooses from a drop-down menu
Dim mySheet As Worksheet 'Creating variable for worksheet
orow = 8 'setting the starting output row

For Each mySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 'this is the first FOR loop, to loop through ALL the worksheets
tabName = ActiveSheet.Name    'this is a variable that holds the name of the active sheet

    For irow = 2 To 10 'This line of code starts the SECOND FOR loop.
        If (Range("a" & irow)) = device Then 'This line of code compares values
            orow = orow + 1
            Range("'SUMMARY'!a" & orow) = device 'This line of code pastes the value of device variable
            Range("'SUMMARY'!b" & orow) = tabName 'This line of code needs to paste the name of the current active sheet
            'Range("'SUMMARY'!c" & orow) = Range("'tabName'!b" & irow) 'this line of code needs to paste whatever value is in the other sheet's cell
            'Range("'SUMMARY'!d" & orow) = Range("'tabName'!c" & irow) 'same objective as the last line of code, different rows and columns
        End If
    Next irow 'This line of code will iterate to the next orow. This is where I get an error (Compile Error : Next Without For)*******
Next mySheet 'This line of code will iterate to the next sheet

End Sub
```

Currently the code runs, but it is only outputting results from the first (main sheet). It needs to skip the first sheet and iterate through the rest of them.

Comment: As commented on your previous question, normal practice is not to use the worksheet name inside `Range`, but instead to qualify the `Worksheet`: `Worksheets("SUMMARY").Range("A" & orow)`.

Comment: Either loop by index (`For i = 2 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count`), or use an `If` to skip the first worksheet.

Comment: It's unclear from your code, but apparently you expect `Range("a" & irow)` to come from `mySheet`, and the other `Range`s from the sheet called Summary. Because you never [expressed that intention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17790711/11683) with explicit sheet references, it does not happen.

Comment: Don't use the worksheet name (`tabName`) inside the loop either. Use `mySheet`: `mySheet.Range("B" & irow)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws  As Worksheet
Dim mySheet As String
mySheet = "mainSheet" 'Insert in the mySheet variable the name of your main sheet
device = Cells(6, 1)
orow = 8
For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> mySheet Then
        For irow = 2 To 10
            If ws.Range("A" & irow) = device Then
                orow = orow + 1
                Range("'SUMMARY'!a" & orow) = device
                Range("'SUMMARY'!b" & orow) = ws.Name
                'Range("'SUMMARY'!c" & orow) = Range("'tabName'!b" & irow) 'this line of code needs to paste whatever value is in the other sheet's cell
                'Range("'SUMMARY'!d" & orow) = Range("'tabName'!c" & irow) 'same objective as the last line of code, different rows and columns
            End If
        Next irow
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: `Range("A" & irow)` needs to be qualified with the `Worksheet` in question.

Comment: very correct!
ws.Range("A" & irow) I believe it would do

Answer (score 0):

### Update Summary Worksheet

Link: [StrComp Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function)

- The following is not tested.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub loopOverSheets()
    
    Const tName As String = "Summary"
    Const tFirstRow  As Long = 8
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tName)
    Dim device As String
    device = tgt.Cells(6, 1).Value
    Dim tRow As Long
    tRow = tFirstRow
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim sName As String
    Dim i As Long
    For Each src In wb.Worksheets
        sName = src.Name
        If Not StrComp(sName, tName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            For i = 2 To 10
                If StrComp(src.Range("A" & i), device, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    tRow = tRow + 1
                    tgt.Range("A" & tRow).Value = device
                    tgt.Range("B" & tRow).Value = sName
                    tgt.Range("C" & tRow).Value = src.Range("B" & i).Value
                    tgt.Range("D" & tRow).Value = src.Range("C" & i).Value
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next src

    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```