# Running Automaticaly vba Macro in all worksheets when open xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

Why is not working automatically this vba macro in all worksheets?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cRow As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row
        For cRow = 1 To LastRow
            If Cells(cRow, 15) = "OnGoing" Then
                Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
                Rows(cRow).Font.Color = RGB(156, 204, 0)
            End If
            If Cells(cRow, 15) = "Modified" Then
                Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next cRow
        Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong on it?

Comment: this line `LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row` would be more resilient by being written as `ws.cells(ws.cells.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You have used 'With ws' which indicates that you want to use ws as the qualifying reference.  However, you did not put a '.' in front of your Cell , Rows and Columns methods.  As a consequence your Cells ,Rows  and Column methods will only ever refer to the ActiveWorksheet.  You should change to using .Cell ,.Rows and .Columns (i.e. ws.Rows , ws.Cells and ws.Columns)

Comment: Two links for you [Fully qualify your cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)  as @freeflow mentioned and [Finding the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `public sub` called `auto_open` to run code on opening an `xlsm` workbook - what youve constructed seems consistent with MS documentation, but `auto_open` in a project module always works with no problems ..

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

If the module is being triggered (put a `msgbox` in to verify) then it could be because you are not using fully qualified range/cell names, so you need `.` in front of `cells` and `rows`

```
            If .Cells(cRow, 15) = "OnGoing" Then
                .Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
                .Rows(cRow).Font.Color = RGB(156, 204, 0)
            End If
            If .Cells(cRow, 15) = "Modified" Then
                .Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

@freeflow did you mean this one?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cRow As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For cRow = 1 To LastRow
            If ws.Cells(cRow, 15) = "OnGoing" Then
                ws.Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
                ws.Rows(cRow).Font.Color = RGB(156, 204, 0)
            End If
            If ws.Cells(cRow, 15) = "Modified" Then
                ws.Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next cRow
        ws.Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

it is working on the activeworkingsheet yet.

Comment: Already working properly. 

Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

You can try activating the sheet before doing the calculation, so your code should look like

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cRow As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        .activate
        LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row
        For cRow = 1 To LastRow
            If Cells(cRow, 15) = "OnGoing" Then
                Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
                Rows(cRow).Font.Color = RGB(156, 204, 0)
            End If
            If Cells(cRow, 15) = "Modified" Then
                Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next cRow
        Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a very bad way to resolve the issue.  The correct solution is to prefix with '.' as I show in my comment to the original post.

Comment: I agree with @freeflow: You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)