# Using range from a column to sum corresponding values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

My data has two columns.
Column C (Alphabets - A, B, C ...)
Column D (Value - 1, 2, 3 ...).
Each alphabet has its corresponding value.

I am trying to locate two cells (e.g. "G" to "J") from column C to set the range, then use this range to sum the corresponding values in column D (i.e. 7 + 8  +9 + 10 = 34).

I tried `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH`. The `MATCH` code returned Error 2015.

```vb
Sub loop1()
    'Dynamic range for cells with data
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("HU").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row '
    LastRow1 = LastRow - 1
    Rng = "C1:D" & LastRow1
    matchrng = "C1:C" & LastRow1

    'Locate start cell in data
    alphabet_start = "G"
    locate_start = Application.Match(alphabet_start, matchrng, 0)

    'Determine end cell
    alphabet_end = "J"
    'WIP_end = Application.VLookup(alphabet_end, myrange, 2, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to use VBA for this? You can use Excel formula for this as well. For example `=IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0))),"Not Found")`

Comment: Wow. I didnt expect to that this could be done with just formulas... This gave me the same output as the code! Thanks a lot Sir!

Comment: one more question.. if i want to present the sum in another sheet in the same workbook, how should i change the formula?

Comment: I have put together an answer which explains it all (I hope?).

Comment: Was trying to understand the formula with the limited knowledge I have, but your explanation cleared all my doubts. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using Excel formulas as well.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0))),"Not Found")
```

To understand this, let's create a basic formula and then break up the formula to understand how it works.

Let's say, your worksheet looks like

[image]

So what we want is `=SUM(D7:D10)`? So let's break this up.

The formula can be broken up as `=SUM("D" & "7" & ":D" & "10")`. Do not yet directly enter this in the cell. It will not work. Ok next thing is to make it dynamic so that we can get the `7` & `10`. Now `7` is the position of `G` and `10` is the position of `J` which we can get using `MATCH`. For example

```
MATCH("G",C:C,0) and
MATCH("J",C:C,0)
```

So the formula can now be written as

```
=SUM("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0))
```

`"D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0)` is just a string at the moment. You have to use `INDIRECT` to tell excel to consider it as a range. So the string now becomes

```
INDIRECT("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0))
```

and then putting it inside the `SUM` formula.

```
SUM(INDIRECT("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0)))
```

One final thing. The `MATCH` can return an error if no match is found so we can tackle that using `=IFERROR(FORMULA,"ERROR MESSAGE")`

So we get our final formula

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT("D" & MATCH("G",C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",C:C,0))),"Not Found")
```

> one more question.. if i want to present the sum in another sheet in the same workbook, how should i change the formula?

Let's say the data is in `Sheet1` so the formula in another sheet will look like

```
=SUM(Sheet1!D7:D10)
```

So now follow the above logic and you will get

`=IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D" & MATCH("G",Sheet1!C:C,0) & ":D" & MATCH("J",Sheet1!C:C,0))),"Not Found")`

Answer (score 1):

You were heading in right direction firezen. Below mentioned code is what you desire.

```
Sub loop1()
    'Dynamic range for cells with data
    Dim LastRow As Long, locate_start As Variant, locate_end As Variant, matchrng As Range
    Dim alphabet_start As String, alphabet_end As String

    LastRow = Worksheets("HU").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '<== Last row of data in Column C
    Set matchrng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HU").Range("C1:C" & LastRow) '<== Set range to Search
    
    'Locate start cell in data
    alphabet_start = "G"
    locate_start = Application.Match(alphabet_start, matchrng, 0) '<== First position
    
    'Determine end cell
    alphabet_end = "J"
    locate_end = Application.Match(alphabet_end, matchrng, 0) '<== Last Position
    
    'If not is error to handle error If alphabet_start or alphabet_end is not found
    If Not IsError(locate_start) And Not IsError(locate_end) Then
        ' Here output is at the end of column D after empty space. You may change as required
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HU").Range("D" & LastRow + 2) = _
        Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HU").Range(Cells(locate_start, 4), Cells(locate_end, 4)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely done. One small suggestion. :) Fully qualify your range. You many want to see [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: Thanks siddharth. I would look into it. I just copied the code tried to make minimum changes