# Code runs fine as regular sub but won't run as Workbook_Open() event

Tags: excel, vba, excel-mac

I have this code in VBA that builds a list of all currently opened workbooks, and adds them to a named range, so that I can use that as input for a selection list. This way the user is able to select the workbook that should be processed.

```
Sub Lijst_bouwen()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wb_pnt As Workbook
Set wb_pnt = Application.ThisWorkbook
Dim wb_overzicht As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb_pnt.Worksheets("Werkboeken")

For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count        'build list of open workbooks
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Workbooks(i).Name
Next i

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1))
wb_pnt.Names.Add Name:="Lijst", RefersTo:=Rng


End Sub
```

As a regular sub this works perfectly fine.
When I try to run it as a `Workbook_Open()` sub it doesn't.

The first line of the code then becomes:
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`

But no results are presented, nor any error messages.

Comment: You need to paste the above code `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` in the `ThisWorkbook` code area

Comment: The code should be in the `ThisWorkbook` Object Module as `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. But this will run fast to count the workbooks open while still opening thisworkbok and will throw error I guess. So, it would be better to run with onTime as ..

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "Lijst_bouwen"
End Sub` ... keeping `Lijst_bouwen` in module

Comment: Also if `"Werkboeken"` is not active then you will get error on the line `Set Rng = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1))`. You may want to fully qualify the cells as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: Thanks @Naresh, that did the trick. If you want to add it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the tip, it is good practice to do so indeed, I dropped the ball on that here. Luckily there is only one worksheet in this folder so it hasn't caused problems (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be in the `ThisWorkbook` Object Module as `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. But this will run fast to count the opened workbooks while still opening thisworkbook and will throw error I guess. So, it would be better to run with onTime as ..

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "Lijst_bouwen"
End Sub
```

... keeping `Lijst_bouwen` in module