# Setting a range from a workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, range

I'm trying to set a range for a Vlookup from another workbook but I keep receiving 424 Object Required Errors and I can't see why

```
Sub DosiDo()
Dim table1 As Range
Set table1 = Workbooks(210721 - LeaveRecords.xlsm).Sheets(Sheet1).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(7, 9))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing double quotes:

```
Sub DosiDo()
    Dim table1 As Range
    Set table1 = Workbooks("210721 - LeaveRecords.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(7, 9))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, so much! However, now I'm getting a 1004 application-defined or object-defined error, do you know why?

Comment: @NickChristensen  Most likely problem is the spelling of the workbook name.  **Check those spaces.**

Comment: The problem is because of [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)