# Select each row and put in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row, excel-2010

In function of the work in my column 2 I want to select the row and copy it in a sheet with the same name. All the time I run the code, a message 1004 error appear.

```
`Sub ventilation()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim dernierelilgne As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' faire une boucle pour effacer les feuilles seelctionner'

For j = 1 To 9
    
    Sheets(j).Select
    LastRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1
        Sheets(j).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next i
    
    Sheets("source").Select
    derniereligne = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
      
      'en fonction du mot dans la colonne, envoyer vers la feuille correspondante'
    
    For k = 6 To derniereligne
    
        Sheets("source").Select
        If Sheets(j).Name = Cells(k, 2).Value Then
        
            Rows(k).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets(j).Select
            LastRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(LastRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
        End If
        
    Next k
    
Next j

Sheets("Source").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

If you have a solution, please !

Comment: Don't [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and don't rely on [implicit references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: What is the `For i = LastRow To 6 Step -1` loop supposed to do ? Maybe `Sheets(j).Select` should be `Rows(i).Select`

Comment: 'for i= lastrow to 6 step -1' is suppose to loop to cleant it's sheet before put the new reference of the "source".

Answer (score 0):

Without Select

Update 1 - LastRow changed to use UsedRange

Update 2 - Match column A

```vb
Sub ventilation()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet, header As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, derniereligne As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' faire une boucle pour effacer les feuilles seelctionner'
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("source")
    Set header = wsSrc.Range("A1:I1")
    derniereligne = wsSrc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To 9
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j)
        sName = ws.Name
        
        LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        If LastRow >= 3 Then ws.Rows("3:" & LastRow).Delete
        LastRow = 3

        'en fonction du mot dans la colonne, envoyer vers la feuille correspondante'
        header.Copy ws.Range("A2")
        For k = 2 To derniereligne
            If wsSrc.Cells(k, "A").Value = sName Then
                wsSrc.Rows(k).Copy ws.Range("A" & LastRow)
                LastRow = LastRow + 1
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox derniereligne - 1 & " rows scanned on worksheet " & wsSrc.Name, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answers but et errase the first ligne and don't copy the row. Maybe it's because I don't understand your code.

Comment: @Cédric What sheet number is `source` ? How many sheets in the workbook ?

Comment: the sheet source is the last one and i have 10 sheets.

Comment: @Cédric erase the first line on which sheet ? `ws.Rows("6:" & LastRow).Delete` deletes all the rows below row 5 on sheets 1 to 9. Note `dernierelilgne As Long` should be `derniereligne As Long` but that won't stop it working.

Comment: he erase the sheet of every sheet (9) and i have already corret the fault `dernierelilgne`

Comment: I don't really undestand the probleme but i need in the sheet except source, the sheet need to be erase before copy the ligne in source. The porbleme is in the code he erase all if I haven't any word in the colum A.

Comment: i think i have correct the problem. I have move `Next j` to clear the sheet before copy.

Comment: the other porblem is i don't understand how he can see the word in column A ? When I run the code he didn't execute the code `wsSrc.Rows(k).Copy ws.Range("A" & LastRow)` and `LastRow = LastRow + 1`

Comment: @Cédric OK, I thought you had a header in line 5 so A5 wasn't blank. Is any column in row 5 not blank ? See updated code

Comment: okai the code said he have scanne 13 row. And I have 17 rows. I don't understand your code, it's to hard for me. The previous code was more easy for me and in the first step clean all the sheet. But it doesn't copy line after line in the good sheet. (you can see the code under me message.

Comment: I have post a picture because i'm not sure to explaine clearely.

Comment: sure, I will put this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

[image: Example]

```
 Sub ventilation()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, derniereligne As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' faire une boucle pour effacer les feuilles seelctionner'
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("source")
    derniereligne = wsSrc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To 9
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j)
        sName = ws.Name
        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Rows("2:" & LastRow).Delete
        LastRow = 2
    Next j
      'en fonction du mot dans la colonne, envoyer vers la feuille correspondante'
    
        For k = 2 To derniereligne
            If wsSrc.Cells(k, 2).Value = sName Then
                wsSrc.Rows(k).Copy ws.Range("A" & LastRow)
                LastRow = LastRow + 1
            End If
        Next k
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it clean the sheet 1 to 9 but don't copy the row in those sheet.

Comment: You are matching column B with `wsSrc.Cells(k, 2).Value = sName` but screen shot shows sheet names in Column A. Also `Next j` should come be after `Next K`. I will update my answer.

Comment: okai thank your fo mutch for your time. I don't understand entirely the code but it work now !