# VBA Table range - function does not include last row of a table

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I am working with macro that creates email and includes Excel table in a body of an email. My problem is that it does not include last row of the table and cuts it off.
Is there anything I can change to avoid last row of the table being omitted?

To define the table range I use following:

```
Dim count_row, count_col As Integer
Dim Actions as Range

count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)))

count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlToRight)))

Set Actions = Sheets("Name of the sheet"). Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(count_row, count_col))
```

Comment: [How to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) for why `Sheets("Name of the sheet"). Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(count_row, count_col))` is problematic.

Comment: The problem is that you're using the *count* of cells as the row *number*. You're off by one because the range you're counting starts in row 2.

Comment: Propably you can use `Set Actions = ActiveWorksheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion` - if you have a continous rows and columns (s. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)

Comment: Thank you all, it is solved now!