# Creating variables inside ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I tried using a variable inside a range with the purpose of doing the necessary rows instead of a pre-determined range.

```vb
Row = Sheets("Checklist").Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row
Parts = 4

For PN = 2 To Row
    Sheets("Checklist").Range(Cells(PN, 22), Cells(PN, 24)).Copy
    Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Parts, 4).PasteSpecial
    Parts = Parts + 1
Next PN

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I receive a sheet with an order for parts. The amount of items that need to be brought over to a data base vary depending on the order.

The layout is somewhat like this:

|  | V | W | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Parts | Version | Yearly volume |
| 2 | 123 | A | 100 |
| 3 | 456 | B | 200 |
| 4 | 789 | C | 300 |

I tried copying line by line creating some sort of loop, in which one of you guys brought up that it's not necessary and you were right.

However, I still need to copy the whole table and bring it to the data base sheet.

For that I used the following code:

```vb
LastRow = Sheets("Checklist").Range("V2").End(xlDown).row

If Sheets("Pipeline").Range("D4") = "" Then
    Parts = 4
    GoTo CopyPaste
    
ElseIf Sheets("Pipeline").Range("D5") = "" Then
    Parts = 5
    GoTo CopyPaste

Else
    Parts = Sheets("Pipeline").Range("D4").End(xlDown).row + 1

End If

CopyPaste:
    
    ' This is the line of code that I'm having problems, it keeps giving me an 1004 error'
    ->Sheets("Checklist").Range(Cells(2, 22), Cells(LastRow, 24)).Copy
    Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Parts, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting please? Difficult to see what your doing. I wouldn't assign "Row = " as a variable, as its a function in vba so just asking for trouble. Try "row1 = "

Also looks like you need to correct your use of " within the copy line. probably looking at something like Cells("&PN&",22):Cells("&PN&",24))

Comment: Are you getting runtime error 1004: Subscript out of range?

Comment: **1.** What error are you getting? **2.** It is advisable to [fully qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) your cells object else you will get an error if Sheets("Checklist") is not active.

Comment: I would say it's an "activesheet" issue on the .cells(x,y) lines.  Is there any need to copy?  Just say along these lines `Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Parts, 4).value = Sheets("Checklist").Range(Cells(PN, 22), Cells(PN, 24)).value`

Comment: See if I was able to clarify my intentions!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we knew what you are trying to copy and past, because you copied a range and paste it to a cell, is that a merged range?

If that is the case, you dont need to use .Copy, you could do something like that insted:

```
my_Row = Sheets("Checklist").Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row
Parts = 4

For PN = 2 To my_Row 
    Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Parts, 4) = Sheets("Checklist").Cells(PN, 22)
    Parts = Parts + 1
Next PN

End Sub
```

Comment: See if I was able to clarify my intentions!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is probably on this line:

```
Sheets("Checklist").Range(Cells(PN, 22), Cells(PN, 24)).Copy
```

Your `Cells(PN, 22)` aren't qualified to a specific Sheet.

However, you appear to be creating a loop for no reason, why not copy across the whole block in one go?

```
Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(Parts, destinationRow).Resize(3, lastRow - firstRow + 1).Value = _
    Sheets("Checklist").Range(Sheets("Checklist").Cells(firstRow, 22), Sheets("Checklist").Cells(lastRow, 24)).Value
```

To tidy it all up a bit, the following should work:

```
'Declare variables
Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, destinationRow As Long

'Set variables
firstRow = 2
lastRow = Sheets("Checklist").Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row
destinationRow = 4
destinationColumn = 4

'Copy data
With Sheets("Checklist")
    Sheets("Pipeline").Cells(destinationColumn, destinationRow).Resize(3, lastRow - firstRow + 1).Value = _
        .Range(.Cells(firstRow, 22), .Cells(lastRow, 24)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was creating a loop for no reason when I could just copy the whole table.

Comment: See if I was able to clarify my intentions!!