# VBA - I can't update other worksheet using range and cells

Tags: vba, range, runtime-error, cell

see the below code, I've no idea why lines 2 and 4 don't work - I get run-time error 1004,

Please help!!

```
Worksheets("Raw rates").Cells(1, 8).Value = 1 'this works
Worksheets("Raw rates").Range(Cells(1, 8), Cells(1, 9)).Value = 1 'doesn't work
Range(Cells(1, 8).Offset(1, 1), Cells(1, 9).Offset(0, 0)).Value = 1 'works
Worksheets("Raw rates").Range(Cells(1, 8).Offset(1, 1), Cells(1, 9).Offset(0, 0)).Value = 1 'doesn't work
```

Comment: `Cells(1, 8)` will refer to the ActiveSheet, not to sheet `"Raw rates"`. You need to qualify *all* references to `Range` or `Cells`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells

Comment: @FunThomas thank you!!!! So simple, that has been driving me insane!! Much appreciated