# 1004 Error on .Apply Line While Sorting By Color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort a given range by cell color.

Getting "1004 - Application Defined or Object Defined" Error on the ".Apply" Line

```
Dim ColRng As Range
Set ColRng = Sheets("Outstanding").Range(Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53))
Sheets("Outstanding").AutoFilterMode = False
Range(Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53)).Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
Range(Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
    Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53)), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB( _
    255, 0, 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding").AutoFilter.Sort
    .SetRange ColRng
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The code initially worked when I used only one cell instead of range but it jumbled all the other columns.

Do I have to add something to qualify this range?

Comment: I had already guessed this would happen ;) Check the link in the answer that I posted below.

Comment: Damn! This was hard to wrap my head around but finally understood and made the required changes. The code is working perfectly now! Thanks for the help Siddharth (and for giving the link to a 9 year old post lol)!

Comment: Glad it got sorted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifiy the range using `.SetRange` where you want to apply the sort. For example

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Out").AutoFilter.Sort
    .SetRange Rng '<~~ Set the range here
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Replace `Rng` with the relevant range.

If you are applying the sort to `Range(Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53))` then use that range there.

**Tip**: Your cell ranges are not fully qualified. It is advisable to fully qualify them to avoid errors as mentioned in [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: Hi Siddharth, thanks for the response. But I am still getting 1004 error, now on the setrange row. Here is the code I used:

Comment: Dim ColRng As Range
Set ColRng = Sheets("Outstanding").Range(Cells(FEnd + 2, 1), Cells(ColEnd, 53))
Sheets("Outstanding").AutoFilterMode = False
*everything else is same as the question, deleting due to comment length limit*
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding").AutoFilter.Sort
    .SetRange ColRng

Comment: Please update the question. Do not paste the code in the comments. it is difficult to ready it. :)

Comment: Sorry! I have updated the question