# Clear all contents of a column except it's header

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clear all contents of a column except it's header.
I used the below code but I got `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`

```
Sub clear_contents_of_column_except_header()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastcolumn As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastcolumn = 10

    sh.Range(Cells(2, lastcolumn).End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Essentially you are doing `sh.Range(42).ClearContents`. What would it mean to pass 42 to `sh.Range()`?

Comment: @GSerg , I need to clear all cells on column 10 ,except it's header

Comment: Try `sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, lastcolumn), sh.Cells(2, lastcolumn).End(xlDown)).ClearContents` you you can simply try `sh.Range("J2:J" & sh.Rows.count).ClearContents`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  LastColumn is variable ,so I am using `cells` .I tried first option and It did not work correctly

Comment: `I tried first option and It did not work correctly` Could you please explain what do you mean? You can also try `sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, lastcolumn), sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, lastcolumn)).ClearContents`

Comment: @@Siddharth Rout , the values on lastcolumn is not continuous (there are a blanks in between) ,So your last variant works correctly

Comment: I had a suspicion about it. And hence I was posting an answer with 2 alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Siddharth Rout LastColumn is variable ,so I am using cells. – Soma
> 14 mins ago

If `LastColumn` is a variable then here are two ways to achieve what you want

```
With sh
    .Range(.Cells(2, LastColumn), .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastColumn)).ClearContents
End With
```

You can also use an alternate method.

```
Dim LastCol As String

With sh
    LastCol = Split(.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1)
    '~~> The below is similar to 
    '~~> sh.Range("J2:J" & sh.Rows.count).ClearContents which is nothing but
    '~~> sh.Range("J" & "2:" & "J" & sh.Rows.count).ClearContents
    .Range(LastCol & "2:" & LastCol & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
End With
```

One important note. Fully qualify the objects (Ex: `Cells`, `Rows` etc.) like I have done above (Notice the DOT before the object). You may want to read about it in [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

Comment: It works and it toke 0.2 seconds to finish  (4k cells) , I thought it can be faster