# Alternative to VBA .Select and .Activate

Tags: excel, vba

I had encountered a problem where my code will work but under strict condition of running it from the view of one specific Sheet. Well, writing it I had a experience of the line working in the same procedure but for the previous sheet (when the code worked the sheet the code operated from was the last one "meaning far right"). Now however due to the procedure of the file I need to run the command from NOT the last sheet of the file. Easy-peasy I had thought to myself, I'll just use .Select to switch to the A1 in the desired sheet and then run the code, false. Select did not worked. Hmm, so I'll just use .Activate and than run my code from the A1 in the desired sheet, false. Activate also did not worked. Weirdly enough if I manually click a cell in the desired sheet and then run the code from another procedure it will always work. Is there an alternative to the .Select and .Activate where I can do indeed switch?
What had just came to my mind. Maybe just end the procedure there and run yet another one staring from intended sheet. And than just run sub after sub in the correct sequence to complete the report.
Would somebody be so kind to help?
Matt

This is the code I try to execute (remember it works just fine as long as it's run from the correct sheet, in my case Worksheets("Without manual clearings")). When I however end up in the other Sheet due to the structure of the report I do need to create, it does not work from there.

```
Sub test()
Dim Arkusz As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Arkusz = Nothing
Set Arkusz = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Without manual clearings")

'THERE IS THE LITTLE DEVIL:
Arkusz.Range(Arkusz.Range("A1"), Cells(Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Same issue as I use `Application.ScreenUpdating` or not. I need to clear variable every time so therefore I use `Set Arkusz = Nothing` to do so.

I wanted to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Without manual clearings").Range("A1").Select` or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Without manual clearings").Range("A1").Activate` before I copy, but it is where I fail.
When I succeed with switching the "view" to the Worksheets("Without manual clearings") I'll be able to run the thing further.

My errors on .Select and .Activate

[image: .Select VBA Error]

[image: .Activate VBA Error]

Comment: You can't select a range from another sheet without selecting that sheet first. I'm not sure what you are asking, did you just want to copy that column from the sheet you are on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set it to Nothing, when declaring an object variable, it's automatically Nothing (just like the base value of an integer/long is 0 and a boolean is False).
For the last cell, it's better to go from lowest -> up, most-right -> left, i.e. `Cells(Arkusz.Range("A" & Arkusz.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Arkusz.Cells(1, Arkusz.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)` but to make it a bit easier, you can use `With Arkusz.... End With`

```
Sub test()
    Dim Arkusz As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Arkusz = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Without manual clearings") 
    'position of sheet doesn't matter if you use its name

    'THERE IS THE LITTLE DEVIL:
    With Arkusz
        .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With
    'could set a range variable first to make it more readable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Oh you already had posted an answer. When I started writing a post, there was only one answer :D You  beat me to it.

Comment: Same with me and iDevlop hehe, you had an explanation around the need to fully qualify Cells so definitely keep yours!

Comment: Hello @Notus_Panda,
"position of sheet doesn't matter if you use its name", there is the ting. It never did. But strangely enough it does now. 
I used:
```
Arkusz.Range(Cells(Arkusz.Range("A" & Arkusz.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, Arkusz.Cells(1, Arkusz.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column), Arkusz.Range("A1")).Copy
``` now and it works like a charm, BUT ONLY when run out of Worksheets("Without manual clearings").
I tested Your <With> method and now it worked (even from the different Sheet)! THANK YOU for your knowledge and quick reaction!
Man VBA does have its quirks.

Comment: Like Siddarth said, it's better to always qualify the ranges you're working with, otherwise VBA is guessing "it needs to be from the active sheet". So because of its quirkiness/rules, we have to guide it (fully).

Answer (score 2):

`Cells(Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))`

You `Cells` object is not fully qualified. You may want to read up on [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

What you are trying to do can be simplified. (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim Arkusz As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Arkusz = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Without manual clearings")

    With Arkusz
        '~~> Find Last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Find last column in 1st row
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        '~~> This is required because of SpecialCells
        '~~> Whenever using SpecialCells, always pad it with OERN.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngToCopy = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Would really suck if the entire range was hidden but a good error catch regardless ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think the initial object ref should be removed, and the end of range could be greatly simplified.

```
'THERE IS THE LITTLE DEVIL:
Arkusz.Range(Arkusz.Range("A1"), Cells(Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, Arkusz.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

should become:

```
With Arkusz
    Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlright)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End with
```

eventually, you could make it even shorter by using CurrrentRegion:

```
Arkusz.range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

but that requires that the "region" has no blank rows/columns. Look at the doc for CurrentRegion.