# Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba

For about seven months, I've been using a piece of code without experiencing any issues. However, a few weeks ago, I started to continuously receive error 1004, which states 'Unable to get the VLOOKUP property of the WorksheetFunction class.':
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2S4k.png)

Below is the code in question. Please note that I've replaced certain names with numbers and letters for privacy reasons:

```
Sub import()

Dim 1_wb As Workbook
Dim Sheet1, Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim A, _
    B, _
    C, _
    D, _
    E, _
    F, _
    G, _
    H, _
    I, _
    J, _
    K, _
    L, _
    M, _
    N, _
    O, _
    P, _
    Q, _
    R, _
    S As Variant
Dim FirstRow, LastRow As Long
Dim FirstColumn, LastColumn As String
Dim TableArray As Range

Set Sheet1= Worksheets("Sheet1")

P = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
If P = "" Then
    Sheet1.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text = ""
    MsgBox "Please Input P"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set 1_wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="x.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Set Sheet2 = 1_wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
FirstColumn = "F"
LastColumn = "GP"
FirstRow = 23
LastRow = 3617
Set TableArray = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error Resume Next
    Sheet.Columns(6).Hidden = False
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Sheet1.Range("F:F").Find(P, , xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

    A = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 8, False)
    B = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 42, False)
    C = Format(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 32, False), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    D = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 22, False)
    E = Format(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 24, False), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    F = Format(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 25, False), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    G = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 23, False)
    H = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 27, False)
    I = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 29, False)
    J = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 85, False)
    K = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 84, False)
    L = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 35, False)
    M = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 30, False)
    N = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 175, False)
    O = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 171, False)
    Q = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 117, False)
    R = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 39, False)
    S = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 163, False)
    
    Sheet1.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text = "A: " & A & vbNewLine & _
                                                "B: " & B & vbNewLine & _
                                                "C: " & C & vbNewLine & _
                                                "D: " & D & vbNewLine & _
                                                vbNewLine & _
                                                "E: " & E & vbNewLine & _
                                                "F: " & F & vbNewLine & _
                                                "G: " & G & vbNewLine & _
                                                "H: " & H & vbNewLine & _
                                                vbNewLine & _
                                                "I: " & I & vbNewLine & _
                                                "J: " & J & vbNewLine & _
                                                "K: " & K & vbNewLine & _
                                                "L: " & L & vbNewLine & _
                                                "M: " & M & vbNewLine & _
                                                vbNewLine & _
                                                "N: " & N & vbNewLine & _
                                                "O: " & O & vbNewLine & _
                                                "Q: " & Q & vbNewLine & _
                                                "R: " & R & vbNewLine & _
                                                "S: " & S
    1_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Else:
    1_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Sheet1.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text = ""
    MsgBox "No Data Found for " & P & "."
End If

End Sub
```

The line that cause the error is:
A = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(P, TableArray, 8, False)

When the variant 'P' is not found, the system correctly returns the expected message, 'No Data Found.' However, when 'P' is indeed present in the table, I consistently encounter error 1004. I've sought solutions online to rectify this issue but to no avail. I'm hopeful you'll be able to assist me.

Comment: Your screenshot is not related at all with vlookup function, but with **match** property. Is there any other part of your code where you use it?

Comment: What happens when you fully qualify the range in `Set TableArray = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))`. Something like `Set TableArray = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Sheet1.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I added the wrong screenshot, I updated it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I cannot believe it worked as a charm. Thank you so much. Do you know why the code was working fine for months and suddently didn't work?

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells) will answer your question...